# #1292 Incorrect date time value error in MySQL when running a query

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to filter my data between two dates. but its throwing an error.

Warning: #1292 Incorrect datetime value: '1631254384' for column `.`.`date_field` at row 1

the query which I'm running is:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `tblletter` 
WHERE (date(date_field) BETWEEN '2021-09-10' AND '2021-09-15')
```

date_field looks like this

[image: date_field looks like this]

I looked up for the error on google and found that their might be some issue with sql_mode. but  I still couldn't resolve it.

[image: my sql_mode]

Comment: You can try DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(date_field) instead of date(date_field)

Answer (score 0):

`date_field` contains a Unix timestamp, not a `DATETIME` or a string that can be parsed as a date. Use the `FROM_UNIXTIME()` function to convert it to a `DATETIME`.

```
SELECT * 
FROM `tblletter` 
WHERE (DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(date_field)) BETWEEN '2021-09-10' AND '2021-09-15')
```